# Java android retofit get

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I did this and it doesn't work

```
   @Headers("Accept: application/json")
    @GET("objects/last_state/?modify_after={date}")
    Call<State> getUpdate(@Header("Authorization") String token,  @Path("date") String date);
```

on SyncHttpClient i did this :

```
syncHttpClient.get(context, "https://****/objects/last_state?modify_after=" + lastModify, headers, null, handler);
```

and it work. What did I do wrong in that?

I call this method :

```
MyApplication.retrofitInterface.getUpdate("SCToken " + singleton.getUid(), singleton.getLastModify()).enqueue(new Callback<State>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<State> call, Response<State> response) {
                    Log.e("tak", "tak");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<State> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("nie", "nie");

                }
            });
```

Comment: What didn't worked when using retrofit ?

Comment: @VivekMishra I call this method and I don't see nothing . I don;t have onResponse and onFailure

Comment: use http logging interceptor library to log your retrofit request and response. That will help you to debug it better

Comment: @VivekMishra maybe I do something wrong ?

Comment: @VivekMishra I edited my question

Comment: I think you need to replace `@Path("date")` with `@Query("modify_after")` and remove `?modify_after={date}` from Path

Comment: @cricket_007 thank ypu now it works !

Answer (score 3):

Try use a @Query in Retrofit to this type of request with get (?=)

```
@Headers("Accept: application/json")
@GET("objects/last_state/")
Call<MovieResult> getAllMovies(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Query("modify_after") String date);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Retrofit you need to express the `?modify_after={date}` part of the path as a `@Query("name")` parameter of the method.

So, replace `@Path("date")` with `@Query("modify_after")`, and just put `@GET("objects/last_state")`